# Combining SQL Tables for one source of information

Tags: sql

I'm trying to combine 3 different tables into one single row in a query but having some problems. Currently I have four tables; PaintSched, Painted_Log, Paint_Defect, and Paint_Inspection.

PaintSched - Single entry, when scheduler just schedules some parts to be painted

```
LOT QTY
1   150
2   100
```

Painted_Log - The paint department then takes the lot and says how many they were able to paint

```
LOT(FK) QTYPainted
1       145
2       100
```

Paint_Defect - Master List of defects for paint inspection after parts have been painted. We hand inspect all of our parts that we paint for quality.

```
 DID   Defect
 1     Scratch
 2     Paint Run
```

Paint_Inspection - Everytime a defect is found the inspector hits a correlating button and the following gets logged. Lot is FK and DID stands for Defect ID from Paint_Defect. QTY is always 1

```
Lot(FK)  DID(FK) QTY
1        1       1
1        1       1
1        2       1
1        1       1
2        2       1
1        2       1
2        1       1
```

What I'm trying to get is the following output:

```
Lot Sched Painted Scratch Paint Run
1   150   145     3       2
2   100   100     1       1
```

I've tried the following to no avail:

```
 SELECT PaintSched.Scheduled,   PaintSched.Lot,    PaintSched.qty,   PaintSched.Is_Painted,   Painted_Log.falloff 
 FROM PaintSched   
   INNER JOIN Painted_Log ON PaintSched.Lot = Painted_Log.lot   
   INNER JOIN MPA_Desc ON MPA_Desc.MPAID = PaintSched.MPAID   
   inner JOIN (
     SELECT lot,  sum(Paint_Inspection.qty) as seds   
     FROM Paint_Inspection   
     WHERE Paint_Inspection.Status = '1'
   ) AS seeds ON PaintSched.Lot = Paint_Inspection.Lot
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  PS.Lot,
  PS.Qty Sched,
  Painted,
  Scratch,
  PaintRun
FROM PaintSched PS
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT
                Lot,
                SUM(QTYPainted) Painted
              FROM Painted_Log GROUP BY Lot) PL
     ON PS.Lot = PL.Lot
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT
                Lot,
                SUM(CASE WHEN DID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Scratch,
                SUM(CASE WHEN DID = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) PaintRun
              FROM Paint_Inspection GROUP BY Lot) PI
      ON PS.Lot = PI.Lot
```

[Try that in SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e82fea9/7/0)

The code above uses conditional sum to roll up the defect count by type before joining that to the lot id. If you have more than 2 statuses, you will need to update the above code accordingly.

Comment: This also works great, Thank you for your input I greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. You should have a group by in the subquery
2. When you alias the subquery, you don't join it properly

See the edits to your query below:

```
SELECT 
  PaintSched.Scheduled,   
  PaintSched.Lot,    
  PaintSched.qty,   
  PaintSched.Is_Painted,   
  Painted_Log.falloff 
FROM PaintSched   
INNER JOIN Painted_Log ON PaintSched.Lot = Painted_Log.lot   
INNER JOIN MPA_Desc ON MPA_Desc.MPAID = PaintSched.MPAID   
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT lot,  sum(Paint_Inspection.qty) as seds   
    FROM Paint_Inspection   
    WHERE Paint_Inspection.Status = '1'
    GROUP BY Paint_Inspection.lot -- Missing GROUP BY
  ) AS seeds 
ON PaintSched.Lot = seeds.Lot
```

Comment: Awesome, Thank you so much!

Comment: Not a problem!  Good luck on stack overflow!

Comment: Quick question, will this also pull values for Lots, even if there isn't a listed defect. Like if there was only paint runs and no scratches, will it show that lot as well since it's in Inner join instead of full?